# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/reactivestreams/client/MongoClients

Tags: java, mongodb, eclipse

Estoy intentando realizar mi primera conexión con Mongodb en Java pero obtengo siempre este error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/reactivestreams/client/MongoClients
    at prbMongodb02.prbMongodb02.main(prbMongodb02.java:12)
```

El código en Java es:

```
package prbMongodb02;

import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoDatabase;

public class prbMongodb02 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Prueba conexión MongoDB");
        MongoClient mongoClient;
        mongoClient = MongoClients.create();
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("app1");
    }
}
```

Estoy utilizando Eclipse como IDE, Mongodb 5.0 y el driver mongodb-driver-reactivestreams-4.4.0 que está agregado al proyecto (Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries), todo en Windows 10.

En este cuadro se puede ver la compatibilidad de versiones entre Mongodb y el driver de Java
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/compatibility/

[image: Java Build Path]

Comment: Te falta añadir la librería o librerías correspondientes, al classpath que usas cuando corres tu clase. Esa excepción siempre te dice "el que compiló esto tenía esta clase disponible al compilar, pero ahora que ejecuto ya no la veo"

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta alfabravo en las variables de entorno del sistema ya agregué el CLASSPATH C.\,,,\jdk,,,\bin" ¿te referís al classpath que figura en el proyecto de Eclipse?

Comment: Toca añadir el directorio donde estén esos JAR :)

Comment: Muchas gracias nuevamente por tu respuesta alfabravo ya agregué el class folder pero aún sigue dando el mismo error, que no encuentra la clase Clients. Sin embargo no da error si comento esa línea.  Es decir, a la clase Client si la ve.

Comment: A ver. Tu código compila? Cuando le das Build en Eclipse, compila? Significa que los imports están bien. Si comentas la línea del import y vuelves a compilar (si lo corres dentro de Eclipse, igual se compila primero), seguro va a fallar la línea donde haces `mongoClient = MongoClients.create()`. **No es el class folder lo que debes añadir porque ahí sólo está el .class de lo que estás haciendo**. Mira que tu proyecto tiene unos external resources, debe haber unos JAR de mongo y de otras cosas, ESOS SON LOS QUE NO ESTÁN disponibles al HACER RUN de tu clase.

Comment: Compila, el JAR del driver de Mongodb está agregado y también el classpath como se ve en la imagen que acabo de agregar.

Comment: Correcto. Una cosa es eso que tiene por título JAVA BUILD PATH (cuando compilas!) y otra cosa es cuando CORRES. La configuración del Run.